# C++ header-only library with waf

Tags: c++, waf, header-only

Good day,
before fully migrating to waf (1.7.5), I have tried to create a simple project of this structure:

```
wafproject
├── application
│   ├── main.cpp
│   └── wscript
├── library1
│   ├── foo1.hpp
│   ├── foo2.hpp
│   └── wscript
└── wscript
```

This is the root `wscript`:

```
def options(opt) :
    opt.load('compiler_cxx')

def configure(cnf) :
    cnf.load('compiler_cxx')

def build(bld) :
    bld.recurse('library1')
    bld.recurse('application')
```

This is the `application` `wscript`:

```
def build(bld) :
    bld( features = 'cxx cxxprogram'
       , target = 'application'
       , source = 'main.cpp'
       , use = ['library1']
       )
```

This is the `library1` `wscript`

```
def build(bld) :
    bld( name = 'library1'
       , inludes = '../../'
       , export_inludes = '../../'
       )
```

(Note: I have tried using `target` instead of `name` for `library1`, and I have also
tried enabling `cxx cxxshlib` features for `library1`.)

This is the `main.cpp`:

```
#include <wafproject/library1/foo1.hpp>
#include <wafproject/library1/foo2.hpp>

int main()
{
}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Setting top to                           : /home/<path>/wafproject 
Setting out to                           : /home/<path>/wafproject/build 
Checking for 'g++' (c++ compiler)        : /usr/bin/g++ 
'configure' finished successfully (0.038s)
Waf: Entering directory `/home/<path>/wafproject/build'
[1/3] cxxshlib:  -> build/library1/liblibrary1.so
[2/3] cxx: application/main.cpp -> build/application/main.cpp.1.o
../application/main.cpp:1:40: fatal error: wafproject/library1/foo1.hpp: Directory or file does not exist.
compilation terminated.
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/<path>/wafproject/build'
Build failed
 -> task in 'application' failed (exit status 1): 
        {task 139729350901264: cxx main.cpp -> main.cpp.1.o}
['/usr/bin/g++', '../application/main.cpp', '-c', '-o', 'application/main.cpp.1.o']
```

I do not want to change the way I include the headers, but for that I apparentely need to change the way my project is set up.

I would be glad for any input, thanks.

EDIT: Solved, it was just a typo (`inludes` instead of `includes` and `export_inludes` instead of `export_includes`).

Comment: Try to put your tree into another directory and add a dummy wscript just forwarding the commands. Or move your existing make file one directory level ahead, adjust the paths and retry. Wild guess.

Comment: I have tried the forwarding you mentioned to no avail. I think the problem is that `waf` simply does not add the `../../` to the include paths (see the generated compile comand `['/usr/bin/g++', '../application/main.cpp', '-c', '-o', 'application/main.cpp.1.o']`).

Comment: So, when I add `includes = '../../'` to the `application` target, it works -- but that should not be necessary, since `library1` has that in `export_includes`, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right, silly me. :/ Thank you.

Comment: As it was a typo, consider closing your question, or post your answer and accept your answer ...

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the first thing on google for 'header only library waf', I thought I should post the generic solution.

```
bld(name = 'libname', export_includes = 'PATH/TO/lib/')
```

Which works for me.